# Printing answers for FizzBuzz using winforms

Tags: c#

I have tried to do the FizzBuzz question using the C# and I could do it as the message boxes. But I need to print the answers one by one in a text box using winforms. How can I do this. I have stated the code with this. Please can you help me.

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int x;
   for (x = 1; x < 16; x++)
    {
        if (x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 ==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FizzBuzz");
        }
        else if (x % 3 == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fizz");
        }
        else if (x % 5 == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Buzz");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should really be the follow-up question to the Fizzbuzz problem, then :D

Answer (score 0):

A TextBox has a Text property, which is a string. You can concatenate strings using the `+` operator. The rest you should be able to figure out yourself.

Comment: When I add "textBox4.Text = ("FizzBuzz" + "\r\n");" to the every line, it only display the last number of the loop. Can you please describe little bit?

Comment: Well, how would you *append* text to a string? I left the hint about concatenation not without reason.